# Send a variable in where clause LINQ PHP

Tags: php, linq, anonymous-function, yalinqo

For LINQ in PHP, I used https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo

I don't know how to pass a variable in `where` clause.

```
public function filter($arr, $find) {
   Enumerable::from($arr)->where(function($val) { return stripos($val->item, $find) > -1; })->toArray();
}
```

Seems is not working like `$find` is not defined but I send it as method's parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `use` statement:

```
Enumerable::from($arr)
  ->where(function($val) use ($find) {
    return stripos($val->item, $find) > -1; 
  })
  ->toArray();
```